# 404 Not found: Could not find the controller

Tags: services

I am creating a resource for service module

```
function noteresource_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'note' => array(
      'retrieve' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves a note',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_retrieve',
        'access callback' => '_noteresource_access',
        'access arguments' => array('view'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the note to get',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'create' => array(
        'help' => 'Creates a note',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_create',
        'access arguments' => array('note resource create'),
        'access arguments append' => FALSE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'data',
            'type' => 'struct',
            'description' => 'The note object',
            'source' => 'data',
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'update' => array(
        'help' => 'Updates a note',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_update',
        'access callback' => '_noteresource_access',
        'access arguments' => array('update'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the node to update',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
          array(
            'name' => 'data',
            'type' => 'struct',
            'description' => 'The note data object',
            'source' => 'data',
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'delete' => array(
        'help' => 'Deletes a note',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_delete',
        'access callback' => '_noteresource_access',
        'access arguments' => array('delete'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'nid',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the note to delete',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'index' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves a listing of notes',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_index',
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'access arguments append' => FALSE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'page',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => '',
            'source' => array(
              'param' => 'page',
            ),
            'optional' => TRUE,
            'default value' => 0,
          ),
          array(
           'name' => 'parameters',
           'type' => 'array',
           'description' => '',
           'source' => 'param',
           'optional' => TRUE,
           'default value' => array(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Which is created sucessfully.

Now I have also created a `function _noteresource_create($data) { echo "hello"; exit;}` under inc file.

Now when I am accesing resouce as websitename/endpoint/resource/create 
and via Post and passing variable it gives me error:

**Response does not contain any data.**

And:

> Under Status 404 Not found: Could not find the controller.

Does anybody can tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: On the endpoint settings, what is the path that is on the "Path to endpoint" field?

Answer (score 0):

Added **actions** in **create** resource where POST method is using. I hope it would work for you.

```
function noteresource_services_resources() {
  return array(
    'note' => array(
      'retrieve' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves a note',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_retrieve',
        'access callback' => '_noteresource_access',
        'access arguments' => array('view'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the note to get',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'actions' => array(
          'create' => array(
            'help' => 'Creates a note',
            'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
            'callback' => '_noteresource_create',
            'access arguments' => array('note resource create'),
            'access arguments append' => FALSE,
            'args' => array(
              array(
                'name' => 'data',
                'type' => 'struct',
                'description' => 'The note object',
                'source' => 'data',
                'optional' => FALSE,
              ),
            ),
          ),
      ),
      'update' => array(
        'help' => 'Updates a note',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_update',
        'access callback' => '_noteresource_access',
        'access arguments' => array('update'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the node to update',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
          array(
            'name' => 'data',
            'type' => 'struct',
            'description' => 'The note data object',
            'source' => 'data',
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'delete' => array(
        'help' => 'Deletes a note',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_delete',
        'access callback' => '_noteresource_access',
        'access arguments' => array('delete'),
        'access arguments append' => TRUE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'nid',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => 'The id of the note to delete',
            'source' => array('path' => '0'),
            'optional' => FALSE,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      'index' => array(
        'help' => 'Retrieves a listing of notes',
        'file' => array('file' => 'inc', 'module' => 'noteresource'),
        'callback' => '_noteresource_index',
        'access callback' => 'user_access',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'access arguments append' => FALSE,
        'args' => array(
          array(
            'name' => 'page',
            'type' => 'int',
            'description' => '',
            'source' => array(
              'param' => 'page',
            ),
            'optional' => TRUE,
            'default value' => 0,
          ),
          array(
           'name' => 'parameters',
           'type' => 'array',
           'description' => '',
           'source' => 'param',
           'optional' => TRUE,
           'default value' => array(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```